# Soql - single record - illegal assignment from list to date

Tags: soql

Ok, I have run into this before and I know it is simple but I can spot my mistake.

```
date    lastFullReviewDate  = [Select Session_Date__c FROM Employee_Session__c LIMIT 1];
```

Thanks for help,

Comment: `... LIMIT 1].Session_Date__c` will compile though is fragile if there are no records and without an `ORDER BY` is relying on whatever the default order is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is returning a record, but you want just the field, so you can reference it directly:

```
date lastFullReviewDate  = [Select Session_Date__c FROM Employee_Session__c LIMIT 1].Session_Date__c;
```

Keep in mind that this query will throw a QueryException if no rows exist, so you might also want to wrap it in a try-catch block.

Comment: You prefer `try`/`catch` over `List<SObject>.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson If I *require* one record, I use LIMIT 2, no try-catch, and no List.isEmpty. I want to know about those errors. If the record is optional, then I typically use try-catch, since the normal path will go straight through without an extra if statement and temporary variable. I don't think I've ever used List.isEmpty pattern, because it slows down the "has record" path in favor of speeding up the "has no record" path.